# Set color for all elements in `feynman` environment when using `tikz-feynman`

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-feynman

I am trying to draw a set of Feynman diagrams which are color-coded. If I set the color on the entire `tikzpicture` environment, all is well. However, if I pass the color to the `feynman` environment, it seems to have no effect. I've also tried passing `/tikz/<color>`, as well as using the `/tikzfeynman/every vertex={<color>}` syntax, all to no avail.

According to the [`feynman-tikz` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-feynman/tikz-feynman.pdf), passing an option to `\begin{feynman}` should be the same as passing the option to `\begin{scope}`:

> Options which are passed in `〈options〉` apply for the whole environment in the same way that the `{scope}` environment work in TikZ.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(Abase),scale=0.85,transform shape]
    \useasboundingbox (-0.25,-0.25) rectangle (2.75,2.25);
    \coordinate (base) at (-0.5,1);
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid[step=0.25] (2.5,2);
    \begin{feynman}[blue] %% <---- this diagram should be blue
      \coordinate [right=1.5 of base] (Abase);
      \vertex [on grid,below=1 of Abase] (Ai1);
      \vertex [on grid,above=1 of Abase] (Ao1);
      \vertex [on grid,below=1/3 of Abase, dot] (Av1) {};
      \vertex [on grid,above=1/3 of Abase, dot] (Av2) {};
      \vertex [on grid,left=1/3 of Abase] (Avp);
      \vertex [on grid,left=1 of Abase] (Ap1);
      \diagram*[small,horizontal=Ai1 to Ai2]{
        (Ai1) -- (Av1) -- (Av2) -- (Ao1),
        (Av1) -- [scalar, quarter left] (Avp) -- [scalar, quarter left] (Av2),
        (Ap1) -- [photon] (Avp),
      };
    \end{feynman}
    \begin{feynman}[red] %% <---- this diagram should be red
      \coordinate [right=1.5 of Abase] (Dbase);
      \vertex [on grid,below=1 of Dbase] (Di1);
      \vertex [on grid,above=1 of Dbase] (Do1);
      \vertex [on grid,below=1/3 of Dbase, dot] (Dv1) {};
      \vertex [on grid,above=1/3 of Dbase, dot] (Dv2) {};
      \vertex [on grid,left=1/3 of Dbase] (Dvp);
      \vertex [on grid,left=1 of Dbase] (Dp1);
      \diagram*[small,horizontal=Di1 to Di2]{
        (Di1) -- (Dv1) -- (Dv2) -- (Do1),
        (Dv1) -- [scalar, quarter left] (Dvp) -- [scalar, quarter left] (Dv2),
        (Dp1) -- [photon] (Dvp),
      };
    \end{feynman}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: generated TikZ diagram from MWE]

Comment: Try to set the color `blue` as an argument of `\diagram*` and you will get the desired color.  For more information, look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.05437.pdf, Adding styles.

Comment: @DanielN Adding `blue` to `\diagram*`'s argument sets the color of the edges correctly, but then the vertices do not have the correct color.

Comment: I also tested: wrapping each `feynman` environment with a `scope` environment _does_ correctly set all the colors -- somehow, the argument to `feynman` is not passed in "the same way" as an argument to scope would be.

Comment: Hi again!  You introduce the "vertices" with the option `dot` when you declare `Av1` and `Av2`.  It is there that you must provide the color.  The philosophy is to introduce the desired color on each individual element.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, I can provide the color manually for each element. That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid... for now I have simply wrapped each `feynman` environment with `\begin{scope}[blue]...\end{scope}`. It's less than ideal to introduce another environment, but it's better than setting the properties on each vertex as well as edges. I'm mostly just confused about why the `feynman` environment is not behaving as documented.

Comment: Looking at the source, it seems like the `feynman` environment [wraps its contents in a `scope`](https://github.com/JP-Ellis/tikz-feynman/blob/ccf6c94e913e350e395be9cad9c2e49a3422d90d/tikzlibraryfeynman.code.tex#L161) but does not actually pass arguments down to `\scope`...